# migration php 5 to php 7 cakephp

Tags: cakephp, plugins, php-5.3, php-7

I am trying to make test environment for my cake project however the migration from php 5.X to 7.1.0 proves to be a nuisance.

I have succesfully installed a new fresh apache2.4 vc14 x64 bit installation.
This apache installation uses a fresh PHP vc14 x64 7.1.0 installation. Both have been checked and are indeed working perfectly.

Now the problem:

I have a cakephp product using a shared created library in the plugins folder, this was working perfectly in CakePHP 2.8.5 using php 5.x. This plugin is loaded in the bootstrap and used the way cakephp intends us to. However the moment i try to run the old project in the fresh installation it is suddenly unable the load the plugin files. Again everything is loaded in the bootstrap and usage has not been changed whilst moving the content to its new location. I have checked a fresh cakephp installation in the new environment and this is also working splenditly.

I am quite baffled at the moment has anyone having experience using cakephp encoutered this particular problem feel free to fire away with some ideas as to what i might have missed.

i will show some code how everything is loaded and used.

```
 CakePlugin::Load('RemFlex');

<?php echo $this->Html->css('RemFlex.flexdetail'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('RemFlex.flexportal'); ?>
```

the plugin directory looks like this

```
Cakephp_program
  -App
    -Plugin
      -RemFlex
        -webroot
          -js
          -Css
        -Controller
        -Vendor
```

Comment: i did not mention error logs, because i have none, i clearly state that maybe someone has some insight as to something i might have overlooked. that is the question. maybe you should read the question before down grading it.

Comment: @AD7six Found and fixed the problem, i forgot to enable the rewrite module in my fresh apache installation. Thnx for the comments anyway and my apologies for the false accusation, i do want to specify that the only noticable log was a 404 not found in my browser and i do generally search voor a couple of days before creating my own question on the stackoverflow. I therefor maintain my opinion on you calling out my flaws without knowing me or my way of asking questions on this platform. I do read a lot of asked question so i generally know what is important to mention when submitting one.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this problem by enabling the rewrite_module in the httpd.conf file of the apache installation. This enabled my htacces to actually work.